# Silverstripe Solr - Add Multivalued index for Page Object

Tags: solr, silverstripe

I am working on a Silverstripe project that uses Solr as the search. I am using the silverstripe-fulltextsearch module to do this but I can't figure out how to add a relationship into the document. For example I have a product that has been tagged with a few things such as "Phone", "Bluetooth" etc. These tags are dataobjects and are linked to the page with a Many Many relationship. I know these need to be flattened into a multivalued property but I can't figure out when this needs to be done or how it should be done.